# Beamer + MusixTex

Tags: beamer, music

can I use MusixTex with beamer class? It doesn't work for me, only with article. With beamer there are a lot of errors (more then 50). Thanks for advice.

This is without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\startextract
\NOtes\qu{ad}\en%
\endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

This is with 53 errors:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\startextract
\NOtes\qu{ad}\en%
\endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

I am using TeXnic Center 2.0

edited. Sorry about that guys.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Can you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of a document that goes wrong? Can you tell what TeX distribution you're using?

Comment: You have reported the same example twice. However, adding `\usepackage{etex}` just below `\documentclass{beamer}` should solve the issue.

Comment: @egreg so now you don't need to compile with etex but you need to load the package? Do you mind if I add this to my answer?

Comment: I love you egreg, it really works :-D

Comment: @dcmst The `etex` package allows LaTeX to use the extended register set; please, complete your answer with the information.

Answer (score 5):

It should work out of the box. From [Beamer User Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), pag.18:

> When using MusiXTEX to typeset musical scores, you have to have eTEX
>   extensions enabled. Most modern distributions enable that by default
>   both in pdpdflatex and latex. However, if you have an older
>   distribution, the document must be compiled with pdfelatex or elatex
>   instead of pdflatex or latex. Inside a music environment, the `\pause`
>   is redefined to match MusiXTEX’s definition (a rest during one quarter
>   of a whole). You can use the `\beamerpause` command to create overlays
>   in this environment

However, as egreg noted, you still need to load the `etex` package in the preamble so that the etex extension can be used.

Comment: There's no separate `pdfelatex` binary any more. The most recent version of Beamer's documentation talks about `pdfelatex` only in relation to older TeX distributions.

Comment: Yes, I qupted an older version and referenced the latest (I'll update the text)... So it should work out of the box, right?

Comment: It should. The distinction between `pdflatex` and `pdfelatex` has been dropped years ago.

Answer (score 1):

For me works well with Beamer, compile with 3-passing:

```
pdflatex example.tex
musixflx example
pdflatex example.tex
pdflatex example.tex
```

An example is below.
I write especially for guitar songs.
You don't need so many packages and can keep those you want.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{musixguit}
\input musixtex
\input musixbm
\input musixcho
\input musixdat
\input musixext
\input musixgre
%\input musixgui
\input musixlit
\input musixltx % \tx command
\input musixper
\input musixplt  %  Palatino text in music
\newcommand\Red{\color{red}}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip10pt}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-1.5em}} % decrease

%----------TAB-----------
\newcommand\TAB[1]{%
  \setclefsymbol{#1}{\,\rotatebox{90}{TAB}}%
  \setclef{#1}9}

% internal string choosing command
%  #1: string (a number from 1--6)
%  #2: finger
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@str[2]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\@strerror
  \or\def\@strnr{-1}%
  \or\def\@strnr{1}%
  \or\def\@strnr{3}%
  \or\def\@strnr{5}%
  \or\def\@strnr{7}%
  \or\def\@strnr{9}%
  \else\@strerror
  \fi
  \zchar\@strnr{\footnotesize#2}}
% \@strerror could be defined to issue some warning/error

% User level commands
\newcommand\STr[2]{\@str{#1}{#2}\sk}  % with a full note skip
\newcommand\Str[2]{\@str{#1}{#2}\hsk} % with a half note skip
\newcommand\str[2]{\@str{#1}{#2}}     % with no skip
%--------TAB--------------

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn} %\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gkai}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{我已经与基督同钉十字架}
\framesubtitle{加2：20}

\begin{music}
\input musixlyr
\nostartrule
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
\instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
%\setinterinstrument={-1}
%\nobarnumbers
\setlyrics1{我 已 经 与 基 督 同 钉 十 字 架，
现 在 活 着 的 \empty{} 不 再 是 我，
乃 是 基 督 在 我 里 面 活 \empty{} 着；
乃 是 基 督 在 我 里 面 活 \empty{} 着；
并 且 我 如 今 在 肉 身 活 着，
是 因 信 神 的 儿 子 而 \empty{} 活；
他 是 爱 我， 为 我 舍 己，
他 是 爱 我， 为 我 舍 己。}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac44}
\scale{1.0}
\generalsignature{0}
\setsongraise1{-4mm}
\assignlyrics1{1}
\normalmusicsize

\stafftopmarg25pt\staffbotmarg3\Interligne\interstaff{10}\relax
\startpiece
\znotes\loffset{2.2}{\verses{\lyric*{}}}\en
%\hardspace{4mm} %horizental
\Notesp\ibu0g1\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0h}\en
\Notesp\ibu0g{-2}\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0e}\en
\NOtesp\qap c\en
\Notes\ca j\en
\bar % 1
\Notesp\ibu0i{-1}\qbp0i%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0h}\en
\Notesp\ibu0j{-3}\qbp0j%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0h}\en
\NOTes\ha g\en
\bar % 2 
\Notesp\ibu0g1\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0h}\en
\Notesp\ibu0g{-2}\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0e}\en
\NOtesp\islurd0{c}\qup c\tslur0d\cu e\en
\bar
\Notes\qa d\en
\Notesp\ibu0d{1}\qbp0d%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0e}\en
\NOTes\ha d\en
\alaligne % line 1
\Notesp\ibu0g1\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0h}\en
\Notesp\ibu0g{-2}\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqh0e}\en
\NOtesp\qap c\en
\Notes\ca j\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0i{1}\qbp0i%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0j}\en
\Notesp\islurd0k\ibu0k{-1}\qbp0k%
\roff{\tslur0j\tbbu0\tqqh0j}\en
\NOTes\ha h\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0i{1}\qbp0i%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0j}\en
\Notesp\ibu0j{-1}\qbp0j%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0h}\en
\Notes\ca g\en
\NOtesp\qap j\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0e{1}\qbp0e%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0f}\en
\Notesp\islurd0k\ibu0k{-1}\qbp0k%
\roff{\tslur0j\tbbu0\tqqh0j}\en
\NOTes\ha c\en
%\alaligne% line 2
\alapage
\Notesp\ibu0g0\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0g}\en
\NOTes\ha h\en
\Notesp\ibu0e{1}\qbp0e%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0g}\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0f{-1}\qbp0f%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0e}\en
\Notesp\ibu0f{-2}\qbp0f%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0d}\en
\NOTes\ha d\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0d0\qbp0d%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0d}\en
\NOTes\ha i\en
\Notesp\ibu0f{2}\qbp0f%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0h}\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0g{-1}\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0f}\en
\Notesp\islurd0g\ibu0g{-1}\qbp0g%
\roff{\tslur0f\tbbu0\tqqh0f}\en
\NOTes\ha e\en
\alaligne % line 3
\Notesp\ibu0g0\qbp0g%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0g}\en
\NOTes\ha l\en
\NOtes\qa j\en
\bar
\Notesp\ibu0i{1}\qbp0i%
\roff{\tbbu0\tqqh0j}\en
\NOtes\qa k\en
\NOTes\ha h\en
\bar
\NOtesp\qap i\en
\Notes\ca h\en
\Notes\ca g\en
\NOtesp\qap j\en
\bar
\NOtes\qa k\en
\NOtes\qa j\en
\Notes\ca i\en
\NOtesp\qap j\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}

\end{frame}

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]